# Number of N-digit numbers that are divisible by given two numbers

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, largenumber

One of my friends got this question in **google coding contest**. Here goes the question.

Find the number of N-digit numbers that are divisible by both X and Y.
Since the answer can be very large, print the answer modulo 10^9 + 7.

**Note:** 0 is not considered single-digit number.

**Input:** N, X, Y.

**Constraints:**

- 1 <= N <= 10000
- 1 <= X,Y <= 20

**Eg-1** :
N = 2, X = 5, Y = 7
**output** : 2 (35 and 70 are the required numbers)

**Eg-2** :
N = 1, X = 2, Y = 3
**output** : 1 (6 is the required number)

If the constraints on N were smaller, then it would be easy (ans = 10^N / LCM(X,Y) - 10^(N-1) / LCM(X,Y)).

But N is upto 1000, hence I am unable to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question looks like it was intended to be more difficult, but I would do it pretty much the way you said:

ans = floor((10<sup>N</sup>-1)/LCM(X,Y)) - floor((10<sup>N-1</sup>-1)/LCM(X,Y))

The trick is to calculate the terms quickly.

Let M = LCM(X,Y), and say we have:

10<sup>a</sup> = Mq<sub>a</sub> + r<sub>a</sub>, and

10<sup>b</sup> = Mq<sub>b</sub> + r<sub>b</sub>

The we can easily calculate:

10<sup>a+b</sup> = M(Mq<sub>a</sub>q<sub>b</sub> + r<sub>a</sub>q<sub>b</sub> + r<sub>b</sub>q<sub>a</sub> + floor(r<sub>a</sub>r<sub>b</sub>/M)) + (r<sub>a</sub>r<sub>b</sub>%M)

With that formula, we can calculate the quotient and remainder for 10<sup>N</sup>/M in just 2 log N steps using exponentiation by squaring: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Comment: but  c++ cannot store such a huge number. The value can go upto 10^10000. Which is just impossible to store in a c++ variable

Comment: All the math to calculate the quotients can be done mod 10^9 + 7, to get your final answer mod 10^9 + 7

Answer (score 0):

Following python works for this question ,

```
import math
MOD  = 1000000007

def sub(x,y):
    return (x-y+MOD)%MOD

def mul(x,y):
    return (x*y)%MOD


def power(x,y):
    res = 1
    x%=MOD
    while y!=0:
        if y&1 :
            res = mul(res,x)
        y>>=1
        x = mul(x,x)
        
    return res
        
def mod_inv(n):
    return power(n,MOD-2)

x,y = [int(i) for i in input().split()]

m = math.lcm(x,y)
n = int(input())
a = -1
b = -1
total = 1
for i in range(n-1):
    total = (total * 10)%m
b = total % m
total = (total*10)%m
a = total % m

l = power(10 , n-1)
r = power(10 , n)

ans = sub( sub(r , l) , sub(a,b)   )
ans = mul(ans , mod_inv(m))

print(ans)
```

Approach for this question is pretty straight forward,

let, m  = lcm(x,y)

let,
10^n -1 = m*x + a

10^(n-1) -1 = m*y + b

now from above two equations it is clear that our answer is equal to
(x - y)%MOD .

so,

(x-y) = ((10^n - 10^(n-1)) - (a-b)) / m

also , a = (10^n)%m and b = (10^(n-1))%m

using simple modular arithmetic rules we can easily calculate a and b in O(n) time.

also for subtraction and division performed in the formula we can use modular subtraction and division respectively.

Note: (a/b)%MOD = ( a * (mod_inverse(b, MOD)%MOD )%MOD

Comment: there is inbuilt pow function in  python. pow(a,b,c) will calculate (a^b) % c.